# how can i make my delete link split into a yes/no when clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a table full of data, and at the end of the row I have a delete option.

Instead of linking to a whole new page to confirm the delete, it would be neat if the Delete link split into a yes/no link that either deleted the row or changed back to Delete depending on which is clicked. I know reddit.com has a good example of this working in their comments sections.

I tried searching for the answer to this but I don't even know what to call it or what would be used to accomplish it.

Comment: You need to be more clear about which part you want help with. Replacing the "delete" button with a "yes/no" is pretty simple DOM manipulation. Removing the row dynamically will involve some AJAX.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to remove the row dynamically. But I would like the `delete` link to switch to `yes/no` links when it is clicked. `yes` would then delete the row and `no` would change it back to delete. I would also like this to all happen within the table cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always fun to help out a fellow redditor!

You could either do something like an alert so when the element is clicked it alerts and asks the user if he wants to confirm.

```
if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
```

or...

Reddit has when you click delete a hidden element will appear so

```
$('.delete_button').click(function(){

   $('.delete_option').show();
   $('.delete_button').hide();

});
```

if you need more help with updating your database or need more explanation let me know.

here's the coding for the jsfiddle in the comments

HTML

```
<div id="delete">
  <a href="#" id="delete_btn">delete</a>

  <div class="option">
      <span>are you sure?</span>
       <a href=""> yes </a><span>/</span><a href=""> no</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a { 
text-decoration: none; 
color: #888;
font-weight: bold;
font: normal x-small verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;   
}  

.option {
display: none;
color: #888;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 1px;
font: normal x-small verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.option span
{
color: red;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('#delete_btn').click(function(){

    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('.option').show();

});
```

Comment: yes! i just want the yes/no to be hidden "behind" the delete. and i want them to switch when delete is clicked, or switch back when no is clicked, just like the reddit comments!

Comment: well that's great, exactly what I want to do.

Comment: if you need anymore help my reddit username is **Kevintastic** feel free to PM me.

Comment: thanks for your help. i ran into another problem though. every single line in my table changes to yes/no when any of the deletes is clicked. is there a way to only change the one that is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

With markup like:

```
<a id="deleteLink" href="#">Delete</a>
<span id="areYouSure" style="display: none;"><a id="confirmDelete" href="urlToDeleteResource">Yes</a><a id="cancelDelete" href="#">Yes</a></span>
```

You could do:

```
$('#deleteLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $('#areYouSure').show();
}); 
$('#cancelDelete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#deleteLink').show();
  $('#areYouSure').hide();
}); 
$('#confirmDelete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jquery to show the yes no link when the Delete link is clicked.  Then click the Yes would do your delete action and clicking the No would just replace the two items with the Delete option again.

Here is a jquery show/hide reference:
http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

Comment: Would there be a way for me not to have it expand downward like in the demo, and simply just hide the delete when clicked and show yes/no? and if no was clicked then hide the yes/no and show delete

Comment: yes you could hide the delete div and show the Yes No div.  So you would have both divs side by side, hiding the Yes/No div, showing Delete div.  Then when Delete link is clicked you would hide the Delete div, show the Yes/No div.

Answer (score 0):

just like this when using the pure javascript

```
<a href="?somelink" onClick="return confirm('Are You Sure Wanna Delete This One?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the delete button is in a cell in a row:

```
$('.delete').click(function(){

     var delete_it = confirm('DELTE THIS ROW?');

     if(delete_it){
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
     }

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/U33BD/

Comment: This causes a box to pop up and ask to confirm the delete. I would like the DELETE link to change to YES/NO links while still staying within the cell. YES would then delete the row and NO would change the links back to DELETE.

Comment: This answer is not at all what the user asked.